# Reversing rolling mean forecasts time-series

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, arima, forecast

I am building an ARIMA model with timeseries data. Here is my original `df`

```
date         values
-----------------
2018-05-28    0
2018-06-04    1   
2018-06-11    2
2018-06-18    3
2018-06-25    4
2018-07-02    5
2018-07-09    6
2018-07-16    7
2018-07-23    8
```

In order to achieve stationarity I subtracted `actual - rolling mean` from the original dataset with

```
rolling_mean = df["values"].rolling(window=8).mean()
df_minus_rollingmean = df.values - rolling_mean
```

So now `df_minus_rollingmean` looks like this

```
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
6    NaN
7    3.5
8    4.5
```

I have fitted an ARIMA model and generated forecasts

```
model = ARIMA(df_minus_rollingmean)
forecasts = model.fit().fittedvalues
```

Because the model to generate the forecasts were made against the `df_minus_rollingmean` values,  how do I convert the forecasts back to values that make sense when compared to the original dataset?